# getSystemService from non Activity class

Tags: android, android-activity

I need to get LAC and Cid codes in my Android application. However, I need to do it inside a not-Activity class. The code I found is this:

```
TelephonyManager telephonyManager =(TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
GsmCellLocation cellLocation = (GsmCellLocation) telephonyManager.getCellLocation();
int cid = cellLocation.getCid();
int lac = cellLocation.getLac();
```

However, the method setSystemService is present only in Activity classes, and I have not found something to send "some sort of activity" to the class.
Is there any way of do so, without activity ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass `context` as an argument to `constructor` of the class. Inside the `constructor` you can initialize the `TelephonyManager`.

Example :

In class,

```
public class MyClass {

private TelephonyManager mTelephonyManager;

public MyClass(Context context) {
    mTelephonyManager =(TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
}
```

}

In Activity,

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

....

//Initializing class
MyClass myClass = new MyClass(this);

..
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to pass a `Context` object to call `getSystemService()` from it. You can also use an `Activity` object as `Activity` extends `Context`.

Then just call `context.getSystemService()`